# iptables multiple -d flags not allowed

Tags: iptables

I am trying to log all my outbound connections to a file using iptables.

This is my rule:

```
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo ! --destination 127.0.0.1  -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "new_connection " --log-level 7
```

However, if I add another IP destination (multicast) so my rule becomes this:

```
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo ! --destination 127.0.0.1 ! --destination 239.192.0.0 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "new_connection " --log-level 7
```

I get the following error:

```
multiple -d flags not allowed
```

My question is not what does the error mean, but rather how can I exclude multiple IP addresses in my rule? The two conditions

```
! --destination 127.0.0.1
```

and

```
! --destination 239.192.0.0
```

are mutually exclusive so having two rules would effectively be like not having them at all (only worse, as I would get nearly twice the logs)

So is there an "and" operator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For problems of this kind you can define new chains and jumping between them.  You might for example add a chain `LOGGING` and at the beginning of this chain match those packets you don't want to log with an action of `RETURN`:

```
$ iptables -N LOGGING
$ iptables -A LOGGING -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
$ iptables -A LOGGING -d 239.192.0.0/16 -j RETURN
$ iptables -A LOGGING -j LOG 
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
```

This way, all packets coming through the `OUTPUT` chain would first go through the `LOGGING` chain and everything not being for `127.0.0.0/8` and `239.192.0.0/16` would be logged, then control would go back to the `OUTPUT`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it doesn't work the way you want.  From the man page:

> Multiple addresses can be specified, but this will expand to multiple rules (when adding with -A), or will cause multiple rules to be deleted (with -D).

The way to do this is to add rules earlier in the chain to divert the traffic you don't want to log or modify, e.g.

```
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT --destination 239.192.0.0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT  -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "new_connection " --log-level 7
```

Comment: It should be possible to accept 2 answers. In the end I decided to give Andreas the reputation points. Thanks, though, and have an upvote!

Comment: I thought about this answer, too, but the chain-approach has the advantage, that you don't infer with potential additional rules coming after the logging (probably you want to do further filtering and having `ACCEPT`ed some addresses could mess with this).

Comment: Thanks!  Andreas's answer is cleaner, so the accept is well deserved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use comma separated values with `-d` or `-s` to set multiple IPs.
(See discussion at http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/user/210361)

For instance, command

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.235.43,192.168.235.46 -j DROP
```

filters traffic to two servers.

Comment: Best answer, but bear in mind that doesn't work with '!'.